# ¿como puedo implementar una interfaz grafica en el lenguaje de programacion python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

soy nuevo en el lenguaje de python, el proyecto que tengo que realizar es el triangulo de pascal, el cual ya lo tengo realizado pero me falta implementar la interfaz grafica a los modulos que tengo del proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo ver la biblioteca [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), hay muchos tutoriales en Youtube que te van a explicar como crear botones, labels, y todos los elementos que componen una interfaz gráfica.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias lo tomare en cuenta :)

Answer (score 1):

Existen un montón de librerías: puedes ver [aca](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) una lista de ellas.

En lo personal recomendaria TKinter, Pygame o PyQt

Comment: gracias verificare e investigare acerca de cada una

Answer (score 0):

Una biblioteca muy conocida y utilizada es Tkinter como te mencionan los colegas de mas arriba, ademas puedes usar QT u otra.

En stackoverflow en ingles mencion mas de ellas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310130/how-to-write-gui-in-python

Comment: ok.. gracias lo revisare